# Find all matches in column range and copy all value within range

Tags: excel, vba

First time user here. 
I'm also a beginner trying to write a program in VBA for Excel 2010 and here's what I need to do.

I have a workbook containing two sheets, Sheet1 called "Process" 
(have column A with titled "Item") and Sheet2 called "Master" (have column A with titled "Item" and column B with titled "Operation")

I need to compare these two columns A, if there's any data that match, I'd like to copy ALL data from column B "Operation" from sheet "Master" and place it into column B in sheet "Process".

The code from Mr. Mohit Bansal it's working perfectly, but after i try to put the code into real condition of worksheet, i'm facing new problem that if any same data in Column A "Item", it's only copy for first data.

Any help for figuring out how to get past this would be greatly appreciated.

Herewith i edit based on real condition of worksheet.

Sheet1 "Process"

```
-------------------------
|Column A   |Column B   |
|"Item"     |"Operation"|
-------------------------
|20YStandard|           |
|20Y        |           |
|20Y        |           |
|20Y        |           |
|20YF0Blank |           |
|20YF0      |           |
|20YF0      |           |
|20YFGAfter |           |
|20YFG      |           |
|20YFG      |           |
|20YStandard|           |
|20Y        |           |
|20Y        |           |
|20Y        |           |
|20YF0Blank |           |
|20YF0      |           |
|20YF0      |           |
|20YFGAfter |           |
|20YFG      |           |
|20YFG      |           |
```

Sheet2 "Master"

```
-------------------------
|Column A   |Column B   |
|"Item"     |"Operation"|
-------------------------
|20Y        |MLM1       |
|20Y        |IQTM1      |
|20Y        |HBM1       |
|20YF0      |QT1        |
|20YF0      |SB1        |
|20YFG      |FG7        |
|20YFG      |SCR1       |
|21YF0      |QT2        |
|21YF0      |SB2        |
|21YF0      |MG2        |
|21YFG      |FG8        |
|21YFG      |SCR2       |
```

Actual Result =

Sheet1 "Process"

```
-------------------------
|Column A   |Column B   |
|"Item"     |"Operation"|
-------------------------
|20YStandard|           |
|20Y        |MLM1       |
|20Y        |IQTM1      |
|20Y        |HBM1       |
|20YF0Blank |           |
|20YF0      |QT1        |
|20YF0      |SB1        |
|20YFGAfter |           |
|20YFG      |FG7        |
|20YFG      |SCR1       |
|20YStandard|           |
|20Y        |Not copied |
|20Y        |Not copied |
|20Y        |Not copied |
|20YF0Blank |           |
|20YF0      |Not copied |
|20YF0      |Not copied |
|20YFGAfter |           |
|20YFG      |Not copied |
|20YFG      |Not copied |
```

---

```
Sub Button2_Click()

pr = Worksheets("Process").Range("A2:B1000").Value

ma = Worksheets("Master").Range("A2:B8008").Value

Range("B:B").ClearContents

For i = LBound(pr, 1) To UBound(pr, 1)

    For j = LBound(ma, 1) To UBound(ma, 1)

        If ma(j, 1) = pr(i, 1) Then

            Worksheets("Process").Range("B" & i + 1).Value = ma(j, 2)
            ma(j, 1) = "---"

            Exit For

        End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Expected Result =

Sheet1 "Process"

```
-------------------------
|Column A   |Column B   |
|"Item"     |"Operation"|
-------------------------
|20YStandard|           |
|20Y        |MLM1       |
|20Y        |IQTM1      |
|20Y        |HBM1       |
|20YF0Blank |           |
|20YF0      |QT1        |
|20YF0      |SB1        |
|20YFGAfter |           |
|20YFG      |FG7        |
|20YFG      |SCR1       |
|20YStandard|           |
|20Y        |MLM1       |
|20Y        |IQTM1      |
|20Y        |HBM1       |
|20YF0Blank |           |
|20YF0      |QT1        |
|20YF0      |SB1        |
|20YFGAfter |           |
|20YFG      |FG7        |
|20YFG      |SCR1       |
```

Comment: One thing that you can do is define two 2-D Arrays, one for Process table and one for Master Table. Now you can use loops to match the values on the 2nd Array and if there is a match change its value to "-----" so that it doesn't appear in the loop next time. This way you will get around the problem of repeating the same match

Comment: Could you not just use an `Index` `Match` or a `Vlookup`?

Comment: @Tom Yes even that sounds right. I have tried the solution with arrays and it seems faster and with smaller lines of code. Either way both should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Find` `FindNext`

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim finalrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim shtCS As Worksheet, shtFD As Worksheet, rw As Range
    Dim c

    Set shtCS = Worksheets("Process")
    Set shtFD = Worksheets("Master")

    finalrow = shtFD.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With shtFD.Columns(1)
        For i = 2 To finalrow
            Set c = .Find(shtCS.Cells(i, 1).Value2)

            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = c.Address
                Do
                    shtCS.Cells(i, 2).Value2 = c.Offset(0, 1).Value2
                    i = i + 1
                    Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop Until c.Address = firstAddress
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response

Answer (score 0):

This is working perfectly:

```
pr = Worksheets("Process").Range("A2:B11").Value
ma = Worksheets("Master").Range("A2:B13").Value


For i = LBound(pr, 1) To UBound(pr, 1)

    For j = LBound(ma, 1) To UBound(ma, 1)

        If ma(j, 1) = pr(i, 1) Then

            Worksheets("Process").Range("B" & i + 1).Value = ma(j, 2)
            ma(j, 1) = "---"
            Exit For

        End If
Next j
Next i
```

[image: Output]

## New Answer

**Only if 10 Rows Repeat themselves in Process Sheet**

Sub Button2_Click()

```
pr = Worksheets("Process").Range("A2:B21").Value

ma = Worksheets("Master").Range("A2:B13").Value

Worksheets("Process").Range("B:B").ClearContents

For i = LBound(pr, 1) To UBound(pr, 1)

    If i = 11 Then ma = Worksheets("Master").Range("A2:B13").Value

    For j = LBound(ma, 1) To UBound(ma, 1)

        If ma(j, 1) = pr(i, 1) Then

            Worksheets("Process").Range("B" & i + 1).Value = ma(j, 2)
            ma(j, 1) = "---"

            Exit For

        End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you response, it's working perfectly..Once more, if in Sheet Process Column Item, have duplicate data (ie :Range(A12:B21) consist of Range(A2:B11)..After i try, the result in Range(A12:B21) is Blank..Could you please teach me about this?

Comment: Good to know that it worked. Can you accept this as answer. ........... For your next query ... The result in A12:B21 is blank because we are running loop from A2:B11 only. You will have to change the range pr and run the code again to obtain values in A12:B21.

Comment: Dear Mohit, I already modify the range become (A2:B21), but the result still blank..could you help me please?

Comment: I have amended the code .... Thing is now you have to run the code again with new range.. We have to do this because we utilized the master array in the first part of the code and to remove the duplicate we changed it's value to "----" ... Now when the same text from process is being searched in that array, it only contains "----" hence no value is being printed. Hope you get the idea

Comment: For the code itself, I already change into [pr = Worksheets("Process").Range("A2:B21").Value], but the result is still blank for duplicate data..Apologize me that i can't understand for this.

Comment: Change the range back to "A2:B11" & use the complete code in my answer again with range "A12:B21"... That will work. Also you should have specified that there is a copy of range that also needs to be filled, so that anyone answering could have provided you the solution accordingly.

Comment: If this doesn't work, I suggest that you edit your question and include everything that you have tried and isn't working.

Comment: Dear Mohit, Sorry for bothering you, I already edit the question also the result after change the range..very appreciated for your kind help.

Comment: Then some other logic needs to be applied. I will post if something comes to my mind

Comment: No, it's not repetition always..it's just in case (sometimes it's only just 4 rows but always sequence, like 20YStandard, 20Y,20Y, 20Y)